# HTML tag in EJS using partials

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, partials

(1)home.ejs **without partials**

[image]

(2)the result contains
 **html** tag、**head** tag and **body** tag

[image]

---

(3)when using **header.ejs as partials** in home.ejs

with opening **html** and **body** tag
[image]

[image]

the result still contains closing **body** and **html** tag
[image]

Dose that mean I don't need to put html and body tag in partials files?

Answer (score 0):

What you see is [Chrome DevTools Elements panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/edit-dom), The code there is not your html source code. It is how your browser parse and read your html.

So the closing tag is not added by ejs. It is how browser understand your html file. It is added because the browser think there should be a closing tag.

IF you want to know the source ejs rendered, you should take a look at your html source. In chrome, right click the mouse, and **view page source**. You will see what is really generated by ejs.

**Your question : Dose that mean I don't need to put html and body tag in partials files?**

No. You should always write a complete html file to prevent misunderstanding from browser. Not all browser is smart. You page will get problem when you meet an old and stupid browser.